# how to read time zone information

Tags: time, timezone

I was looking at some book of  system programming. It mentioned to use a variable `TZ` with a colon separated list which is used from `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. Probably the book is a bit outdated.

I checked on my Ubuntu system

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia$ file Oral
```

gives following output

> Oral: timezone data, version 2, 14 gmt
>   time flags, 14 std time flags, no leap
>   seconds, 51 transition times, 14
>   abbreviation chars

I tried opening it in vi but the text could not be read.
I also tried reading `/etc/localtime` but here also it could not be read.

1. How can I basically read above type of files?
2. Where is TZ environment variable defined in Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 11):

Well, it depends what you want to read it for?

Almost all programs just rely on `$TZ` being set in the environment or `/etc/localtime` being a link to a timezone file.  The C library will then automatically arrange for eg `localtime()` to return the correct time.

> 1) How can I basically read above type of files

`zdump -v /etc/localtime` will show you what's inside the files.

These are compiled files not meant for humans to read.  `apt-get source tzdata` will give you the source they come from.

> 2) Where is TZ environment variable defined in Ubuntu 10.04

It is not set by default.  Instead, `/etc/localtime` is a copy of the relevant zoneinfo file, and `/etc/timezone` is the name of that zone.

You can change them with `sudo tzconfig` or through the GUI.

You could set it in for instance `~/.env` if you want a different personal default for yourself.

Comment: Creating `~/.env` with `UTC` in it has no effect on the local timezone.

Comment: Nowadays it is tzselect

Comment: `tzselect` is not a replacement for `tzconfig`: it just chooses a timezone and prints it to stdout _without changing any configuration_.  The actual modern replacement is `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.